# Supervisord: To not run any program while running supervisord

Tags: supervisord

I am stuck in a weird situation. I have setup supervisord for around 50 tasks which are running on different servers according to the roles mentioned in the tags of the dynamic inventory.

While invoking `supervisord -c supervisord.conf` It actually starts all of the programs which are mentioned or included in this configuration file.

I just want it to run supervisor daemon but It should not run any program mentioned in it until I explicity ask it to run with below command.

```
supervisorctl start program
```

Any Idea?

Comment: what is actual use case. basic use of supervisor is to autostart service. Or in your case stop the services which you dont want to active using supervisorctl command.

Comment: I am starting supervisord while deployment and I want it should start specific program on specific server but it starts all programs which is the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer. From

http://supervisord.org/running.html

"To change the set of programs controlled by supervisord, edit the supervisord.conf file and kill -HUP or otherwise restart the supervisord process. This file has several example program definitions."

So you can start supervisord with a minimal "do nothing" conf and then uncomment what you want to start explicitly and do a kill -HUP to re-read the conf.